# Modifying an element inside a list of a list of objects state in React & Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Just wanted to get some opinion about a dilemma I'm facing. I'm using MongoDB and Node for the backend and React/Redux for frontend. I'm using redux-thunk to do api calls and one of my data models has sort of a parent-child relationship. To simplify it:

Parent.js

```
name: {
    type: String
    default: ""
},
children: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
    ref: "Child"
    }]
}
```

Child.js

```
name: {
    type: String
    default: ""
},
parent: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID,
    ref: "Parent"
    }
}
```

Now, I'm using redux-thunk to fetch the Parents and store them in a redux state. So my initial redux state looks something like this:

```
parents: [
    { 
        name: "Parent 1",
        children: [{
            name: "Child 1",
            parent: "Parent 1",
        },
        {
            name: "Child 2",
            parent: "Parent 1",
        }
        ]
    },
    { 
        name: "Parent 2",
        children: [{
            name: "Child 3",
            parent: "Parent 2",
        },
        {
            name: "Child 4",
            parent: "Parent 2",
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

And now for example, I have a form in the front end that adds a child and chooses a parent from a dropdown, I can't seem to figure out how to manipulate that parent's list of children. I'm sure adding a child would just be the start of my problems, I'd also have to think about changing name of a child and deleting.

I do have a working backend for this already written in Node and Mongoose where the child gets appended to the list of children of the parent; however, I'm stuck with the redux/react state side of it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if there are two users with the same data stored in redux, and one of the users triggers an action that results in the backend modifying data? Caching things becomes hard quickly. Would it be easier to just fetch the data repeatedly, to minimize the chance of data getting stale for some user? (For your specific problem, I've used [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) to add IDs to your structure (i.e. `parents: [{...}, {...}]]` could become `parents: {"Parent 1": {...}, "Parent 2": {...}}` and the same to the inner `children` array)).